# Comment comprendre la chanson « Au pied d’un rosier » ?

Tags: sens, locutions, paroles-de-chanson, figure-de-style

Voici le contenu d’une chansonnette de *Tri Yann*, appelée *au pied d’un rosier*.

> C'est dans X ans je m'en irai dis au pied d'un rosier ;
>   Dis au pied d'un rosier, au pied d'une rose ;
>   Au pied d'un rosier, mon cœur s'y repose.

Les chanteurs comptent à rebours, commençant par dix. J’ai enlevé des phrases qui apparaissent deux fois dans le couplet.

Il y a des nombreuses choses que je ne saisis pas. Tout d’abord, le morceau « C’est dans dix ans je m’en irai » semble d’aller à l’envers. 
Deuxièmement, quel est la fonction du mot *dis* ici ? C’est une requête de chanter, ou ça sert seulement à prolonger les phrases ou à les rendre plus jolies ?
Et « au pied de », ça désigne les racines du rosier ici, ou ça veut dire quelque chose d’autre ?

Quand je lis les paroles, je me doute que la chanson porte sur un vieil amour que quelqu’un ira voir, mais davantage je saurais rien déduire. Pouvez-vous m’aider à les disséquer ?

Answer (score 4):

Parler de rose fait écho au poème *[Mignonne, allons voir si la rose](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mignonne,_allons_voir_si_la_rose)* que Ronsart composa pour sa bien aimée.

Ou un autre poème de François de Malherbe écrit à la mort de la fille de son ami Cléophon :

> Et rose, elle a vécu ce que vivent les roses
>   L’espace d’un matin.

Plus de précision au paragraphe *[citations](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_de_Malherbe)* sur ce dernier point.

Il semblerait que le texte soit  écrit sur le mode d'une rengaine populaire bretonne, forme de chant qui permettait autrefois de rythmer les travaux collectifs en mer ou dans les champs.

N'étant pas bretonnant (le *[breton](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breton)* est une langue celtique), je ne saurais dire si c'est une syntaxe bretonne, ou un arrangement de l'auteur.

J’interprèterais le texte (sans aucune garantie) comme :

> Dans dix ans je retournerai au pays, près des miens, là où mon cœur à ses racines.
>   Dans neuf ans je retournerai au pays, près des miens, là où mon cœur à ses racines.
>   . . . . .
>   Lalalalala

C'est un contexte folklorique (localisé en *[Bretagne](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bretagne)*) très particulier qui aime les *[ritournelles](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritournelle)* bercées par les 'plaintes' du *[biniou](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biniou)* (cornemuse bretonne).

Comment: Et se pourrait-il que le « je m'en irai » puisse être pris comme l'euphémisme parfois employé pour « mourir » et que soit exprimé le désir d'être enterré au pied du rosier d'où son cœur n'est jamais parti ?

Comment: Bien joué pour avoir vu l'influence du Breton. D’après la page wikipédia, a) "En breton, l'ordre des éléments dans une phrase n'est pas seulement grammatical, il est sémantique" b) "Quand le sujet est élidé" donc pas besoin de mettre je,tu,il .  Le sens de la phrase "Je dis, au pied d'un rosier, 'je m'en irais dans N ans'" avec une tournure bretonne est donc vraisemblable.

Comment: NB: je connais pas le breton, l’élision du sujet est juste commune (latin, espagnol)

Answer (score 2):

Les phrases ne sont pas grammaticalement correctes. Le mot « dis » semble être utilisé comme une interpellation, par exemple « Hé dis(-moi), tu veux sortir ? » ou encore « ça te dit de sortir ? ». Ce mot est probablement juste ajouté pour avoir une syllabe en plus et mieux coller à la musique, mais il faudrait demander à un breton pour savoir si ça ne serait pas une façon courante de parler en Bretagne.

*Au pied d'un rosier/rose* désigne en effet les racines du rosier/rose.

La chanson n'a pas beaucoup de sens, même pour moi qui suis français.

Answer (score 0):

Le *pied* d'un arbre ou d'un arbuste, c'est la partie qui sort du sol.

Pour le reste... partir, s'en aller, est parfois un euphémisme pour mourir, le cœur qui repose fait penser à un amour perdu (et quand c'est au pied d'un rosier l'allusion à *la claire fontaine* est possible).  Mais ce genre d'interprétation va mal avec le décompte.